# Restart myself - can I reinitialize everything from scratch?

Tags: java, restart, application-restart

I have something like this:

```
public static final String path;
static {
    path = loadProperties("config.conf").getProperty("path");
}

public static void main(String... args) {

    // ... do stuff (starting threads that reads the final path variable)

    // someone want's to update the path (in the config.conf file)
    restart(); // ???
}
```

I want to reinitialize the JVM calling the static initializer again, and then `main(...)`!

**Can it be done?**

Comment: why not just run main();

Comment: I think he wants the static initializer block to run again. It only gets run when the class is loaded.

Comment: Can't you just put the body of the static block into the main method? and just call main()?

Comment: why can't you just call the method when the user updates the config.conf file?

Comment: I use `path` (in threads for example) all over the place! Updated example..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start your application using a custom class loader, this will allow you to load and unload your static variables.

However, basically its a very bad design to need to do this.  I like making fields final, but you shouldn't make them final if you want to change them.

Comment: Added an answer with code that shows an example of how this is done!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is simply to reload some configuration files, why not implement a file change monitor?

Here's a good tutorial on this subject:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

I think what you're proposing (restarting your application automatically) would be a little more cumbersome than just watching for file updates.

Comment: I shuld have written my example more precise, I really want to **restart** my program!

Comment: @dacwe Unless there's something more compelling than some configuration information that needs to be updated with a restart, I maintain that you're better off watching the file for changes.  Change your program design to better accommodate dynamic configuration information instead of a raw `static final String`.  Encapsulate your globally accessed configuration in a class.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is simply *not* to use the static initializer for this. Why not just make `path` non-final and load it in `main`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm accepting [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207593/restart-myself-can-i-reinitialize-everything-for-scratch/4208654#4208654) answer but post a complete example for anyone to use!

*I'm not going to use this in production code... there are other ways of doing it!*

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        start();
        Thread.sleep(123);
        start();
    }

    private static void start() throws Exception {

        ClassLoader cl = new ClassLoader(null) {
            protected java.lang.Class<?> findClass(String name) 
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
                try{
                    String c = name.replace('.', File.separatorChar) +".class";
                    URL u = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(c);
                    String classPath = ((String) u.getFile()).substring(1);
                    File f = new File(classPath);

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

                    byte buff[] = new byte[(int) f.length()];
                    dis.readFully(buff);
                    dis.close();

                    return defineClass(name, buff, 0, buff.length, null);

                } catch(Exception e){
                    throw new ClassNotFoundException(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        };

        Class<?> t = cl.loadClass("Test$Restartable");
        Object[] args = new Object[] { new String[0] };
        t.getMethod("main", new String[0].getClass()).invoke(null, args);
    }

    public static class Restartable {

        private static final long argument = System.currentTimeMillis();

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(argument);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this structure

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    boolean restart = true;
    while (restart )
    {
        retart = runApplication();
    }

}
```

If you ever detect the need to restart you application, have runApplication return true.
If it is time to exit return false;

Comment: That will not reinitialize any final variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an UI or a daemon so you can control output to stdout, you can make a wrapper on the outside that starts your program.

If the program upon exit outputs "RESTART" you can restart your program again from this wrapper. If not, it just ends.

Or if you want the pure java way, you can go with a solution with classloaders as Peter Lawrey mentioned in his post. Before going down this route you should really rethink your design (if it is your code) and make your code capable of cleaning itself up.