# Call new JVM from existing JVM

Tags: java

I am writing GUI application, and I want to perform a restart of the application in case the user did some changes.

Currenty I have once main call with the method `startGui` which initialises the gui.
I want to know how I can call this method again but with a new JVM from the existing JVM.

Comment: Something like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207593/restart-myself-can-i-reinitialize-everything-from-scratch/4213988#4213988

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that from within the VM. Instead, you probably need a dispatcher process (It could be a shell script, but it could be any other process as well, including a Java Process).

Anyway, you need to end the current process (using System.exit(someCode)), let your dispatcher analyze the return code and let it restart this application for a given return code.

Comment: but i this case i have another process in the system , can i use the Runtime class to invoke my java class.

Comment: @David I'd use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It's much more comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this in my current project. It preserves the process arguments, the JVM arguments, and the classpath.

```
private static void restart(String[] args) throws IOException {
    RuntimeMXBean mx = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    List<String> jvmArgs = mx.getInputArguments();
    String cp = mx.getClassPath();

    List<String> listArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    listArgs.add("java");
    listArgs.addAll(jvmArgs);
    listArgs.add("-cp");
    listArgs.add(cp);
    listArgs.add(Main.class.getName());
    listArgs.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));

    String[] res = new String[listArgs.size()];
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(listArgs.toArray(res));

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Note that `args` is the argument received by the `main` method. It has to be memorized somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help appreciated.