# java string to class and call mathod

Tags: java, class

I have 2 class

Test.java whith code

```
public class Test {

public void main (String [] args)
{

System.out.println ("Call test");

}

}
```

And second class: MakeCall.Java In this class I have String variable:

String MakeCall = "Test";

Please help: how can I convert String to ClassName and call method main, like: MakeCall.main (args).

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207593/restart-myself-can-i-reinitialize-everything-from-scratch/4213988#4213988.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to know the name of the package containing the class. If you know it, you can try the following:

```
String className = packageName + ".Test";
Class cls = Class.forName(className);
cls.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null);
```

Note that, if the class is in (default) package then you can use "Test" as className without the package name.

Comment: PackageName is "com.main" and I add it: String className = "com.main.Test";

Comment: Thanks!!! And another question: how can I get component on the form (for example JComboBox) and add some Items?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to read up on Java reflection:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

The key parts that you will need are

```
Class class = Class.forName("Test");
```

and

```
Method method = class.getMethod("main", String[].class);

method.invoke( null, new String[] {"arg1"} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to reflection invocation you can create an instance and then invoke like an object as well. Eg

```
Class<Test> testClass = (Class<Test>) Class.forName("Test");
Test obj = testClass.newInstance();
obj.main(args);
```